# QGIS live GPS data via internal GPS (Durabook, Windows 10)

Tags: qgis, gps

I have a Tablet (Darebook with Windows 10) on which I installed QGIS (v. 2.8)  So I tried to do the "live GPS tracking" with internal GPS (Sierra wireless sensor).

Next, from the menu of QGIS I went to "GPS information" and I clicked on the "Autodiscover" but I always get the message "unable to connect to the GPS." So I tried with the other options: internal, serial device, gpsd, but always the same message.

What am I doing wrong? What steps do I need to be able to do live tracking?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Is there any particular reason you chose an old QGis-version?

Comment: No I have not, but I know this version guit well.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet here is to run the latest 3.4 release as that includes an update to Qt (from 4 to 5) which has much better support for built-in GPS in Windows.  The GPS support in Qt5 can now access the Windows Location Services which allows for access to built-in GPS sensors.

Access to sensor data like that isn't supported in any < 3.0 release.  The workaround is to run something to expose the Windows Location Service data to a COM port, which has worked in the past, but a update to 3.4 will be easier IMO.

Comment: Everything works  now well, thanks for the help!